# Convergence in Probability $\Rightarrow$ Convergence in Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Under which conditions the Convergence in Probability implies the Convergence in Expected Value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Vitali convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) gives necessary and sufficient conditions.